# Hyperledger peer node start error

Tags: installation, hyperledger, peer

I am getting the following error while running the command to start the peer node. 
*Error:*

> grpc: addrConn.resetTransport failed to create client transport: connection error: desc = "transport: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5005: getsockopt: connection refused"; Reconnecting to {"127.0.0.1:5005" }

Can anybody help me out ?

Comment: can you please show some code and the steps you have followed ?

Comment: are you behind a proxy?

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me as well after I just set up a development environment in a vagrant VM, following the instructions from http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev-setup/build/.

The connection to "127.0.0.1:5005"  is configured in peer/core.yaml:

```
167:            # orderer to talk to
168:            orderer: 127.0.0.1:5005
```

So, the peer expects an orderer service listening on that port. The oderer service (https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/orderer/README.md) listens on port 5151 by default. This is configured in https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/orderer/orderer.yaml.

Build the orderer with `make orderer`and start it with `orderer`. Adjust the port in `peer/core.yaml` to `5151` (the one that the orderer service listens on), rebuild peer with `make peer`, start `peer node start` and you will see that the error message disappeared and peer starts correctly:

```
...
09:51:50.430 [chaincode] notify -> DEBU 056 notifying Txid:vscc
09:51:50.430 [chaincode] Launch -> DEBU 057 sending init completed
09:51:50.430 [chaincode] Launch -> DEBU 058 LaunchChaincode complete
09:51:50.430 [sysccapi] RegisterSysCC -> INFO 059 system chaincode %s(%s) registered vscc github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/system_chaincode/vscc
09:51:50.433 [committer] NewDeliverService -> INFO 05a Creating committer for single noops endorser
09:51:50.437 [nodeCmd] serve -> INFO 05b Starting peer with ID=name:"jdoe" , network ID=dev, address=0.0.0.0:7051, rootnodes=, validator=true
Nil tx from block
Commit success, created a block!
```

Comment: Great..! Can you please help me with the corresponding environment variable to be configured for peer in the docker-compose file.